# what does StackOverFlowError SpannableString means?

Tags: java, android, stack-overflow

I know that there are some question with this type of error, but mine just happens randomly and I haven't found what is causing it. Here is the error log:

```
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702): java.lang.StackOverflowError
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.text.SpannableString.getSpans(SpannableString.java:25)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.text.TextUtils.writeToParcel(TextUtils.java:615)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.widget.TextView$SavedState.writeToParcel(TextView.java:8781)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1254)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1173)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Parcel.writeSparseArray(Parcel.java:662)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1198)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:591)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1646)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:605)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1170)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:591)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1646)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:605)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1170)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:591)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1646)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:605)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1170)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:591)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1646)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:605)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1170)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:591)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1646)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:605)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1170)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:591)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1646)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:605)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1170)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:591)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1646)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:605)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1170)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:591)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1646)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:605)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1170)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:591)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1646)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:605)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1170)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:591)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1646)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:605)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1170)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:591)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1646)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:605)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1170)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:591)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1646)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:605)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1170)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:591)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1646)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:605)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1170)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:591)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1646)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:605)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1170)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:591)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1646)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:605)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1170)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:591)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1646)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:605)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1170)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:591)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1646)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:605)
11-02 16:41:58.448: E/AndroidRuntime(13702):    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.
```

My app just have 1 `Activity` with 2 `TextView`, 2 `Button` and 1 `EditText`

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
     if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            onSaveInstanceState(newBundy);
        } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
            onSaveInstanceState(newBundy);
        }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putBundle("newBundy", newBundy);
}
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.getBundle("newBundy");
}
```

I commented the lines above and now is not crashing, why is this code making it crash?

Comment: You have a circular dependency between `writeMapInternal`, `writeToParcel`, `writeBundle` and `writeValue`.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I Don't think so. I noticed that it happens when the device is rotated a couple of times and then the home buttons is clicked.

Comment: We would need to see the code.

Comment: One more: what is in `newBundy`?

Comment: @Szymon My bad, forgot to include it `Bundle newBundy = new Bundle();`

Comment: You don't really need to save instance in `onConfigurationChanged` as your activity is not destroyed and re-created in this case. Can you remove that code and try?

Comment: @Szymon I did, and its not crashing. I included it for testing how it works, but it make it crash. I will try again later when I found a need to include it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need to save instance in `onConfigurationChanged` as your activity is not destroyed and re-created in this case. It is enough if you save your bundle in `onSaveInstanceState`.

The code in `onConfigurationChanged` can be removed.